# iPhone - Playing sound when device locked/silent mode but allow apple alarm to sound

Tags: objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer, audio

I have an app called Light Alarm that plays different sounds as the alarm approaches.  I have always used the following code:

```
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback; 
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (category), &category); 
AudioSessionSetActive (true);
```

I use this code to ensure the sounds play even if users have forgotten to switch off 'silent mode' before they go to bed or their device locks.

However, an unwanted side effect of the above code is that if the main apple alarm goes off, it appears on screen, the device will vibrate (if active) but no sound will play.

Does anyone know how I can still have my sound play when on silentmode==ON and when device is locked, but also allow Apple's alarm app to sound?

Cheers, Charlie